# Tkinter Assign Different Functions To Each Ranged Button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

the problem is its only works for one global function.. how to assign each button for a different function

```
from tkinter import*
class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self,master):
        mainFrame=Frame(master)
        mainFrame.pack()
        self.cv=Canvas(scrollregion=(0,0,200,1200),width=200,height=1200,bg='green')
        self.scb=Scrollbar(command=self.cv.yview)
        self.cv.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.scb.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
        self.cv.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scb.set)
        #frame on canvas to pack title frame
        self.cvFrame=Frame(self.cv)
        self.cvFrame_window=self.cv.create_window(5,5,anchor=NW,window=self.cvFrame)

        self.tFrame=Frame(self.cvFrame)
        self.tFrame.pack(in_=self.cvFrame)

        self.t=['Site Preparation','WBLFF','Frame','Roof Construction','Roof Finishes',]
        self.tr=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
        #range button created inside one frame
        for i in range(5):
            self.tButton=Button(self.tFrame,text=self.t[i],bg='purple',fg='white',width=20,relief=GROOVE)
            self.tButton.grid(in_=self.tFrame,row=self.tr[i])
            for i in range(0,1):
                self.tButton.bind('<Button-1>',self.subT1)

    #open up new subtitle under main title    
    def subT1(self,event):
        self.s=['Site Preparation','Site Clearence','Earth Works']
        self.sc=['dark violet','yellow','yellow']
        self.sf=['white','black','black']
        self.sr=[0,1,2]
        self.sFrame=Frame(self.tFrame)
        self.sFrame.grid(in_=self.tFrame,row=0)
        for x in range(3):           
            self.sBtn=Button(self.sFrame,text=self.s[x],bg=self.sc[x],fg=self.sf[x],width=20,relief=GROOVE)
            self.sBtn.grid(in_=self.sFrame,row=self.sr[x])
            self.sBtn.bind('<Button-1>',self.destF) 
    #detroy frame back to main title
    def destF(self,event):
        self.sFrame.destroy()

#root window
root=Tk()
root.title('Built Up Rates')
root.geometry('220x600+0+0')
A=mainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[Open Up The Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Hbm.png)
[Open up the subtitle by clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUAQk.png)

the problem is its only works for one global function.. how to assign each button for a different function

Comment: Do you wanted different functions as the title says? Or the same function that works differently for each button?

Comment: For this statement you can just use row=x as they both point to the same number --> self.sBtn.grid(in_=self.sFrame,row=self.sr[x])

Comment: its almost the same function but different subtitle name.. but for future impact I rather learn making different or multiple function for every button

Comment: n Curly Joe.. thx for the tip :) it work.. juz by using =x

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: you can use **Button(command=function_name)**
in place of bind('< Button-1 >',function_name)

---

Create list of functions

```
functions = [self.subT1, self.other_function] 

for i in range(2):
    Button(command=functions[i])


def subT1(self): # without `event` or with `event=None`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*
class mainWindow:
    def __init__(self,master):
        mainFrame=Frame(master)
        mainFrame.pack()
        self.cv=Canvas(scrollregion=(0,0,200,1200),width=200,height=1200,bg='green')
        self.scb=Scrollbar(command=self.cv.yview)
        self.cv.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.scb.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
        self.cv.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scb.set)

        #Frame to Canvas
        self.cvFrame=Frame(master)
        self.cvFrame_window=self.cv.create_window(5,5,anchor=NW,window=self.cvFrame)

        self.t=['Site Preparation','WBLFF','Frame','Roof Construction','Roof Finishes',]
        self.tr=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
    #range button created inside one frame
        for i in range(5):
            self.tButton=Button(self.cvFrame,text=self.t[i],bg='purple',fg='white',width=20,relief=GROOVE)
            self.tButton.grid(in_=self.cvFrame,row=self.tr[i])
            if i in range(0,1):
                self.tButton.bind('<Button-1>',self.subT1)
            if i in range(1,2):
                self.tButton.bind('<Button-1>',self.subT2)

    def subT1(self,event):
        self.s=['Site Preparation','Site Clearence','Earth Works']
        self.sc=['dark violet','yellow','yellow']
        self.sf=['white','black','black']

        self.sFrame=Frame(self.cvFrame)
        self.sFrame.grid(in_=self.cvFrame,row=0)
        for x in range(3):           
            self.sBtn=Button(self.sFrame,text=self.s[x],bg=self.sc[x],fg=self.sf[x],width=20,relief=GROOVE)
            self.sBtn.grid(in_=self.sFrame,row=x)
            self.sBtn.bind('<Button-1>',self.destF)

    def subT2(self,event):  
        self.s=['WBLFF','Pile Cap','Column Stump','Ground Beam','Ground Slab']
        self.sc=['dark violet','yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow']
        self.sf=['white','black','black','black','black']

        self.sFrame=Frame(self.cvFrame)
        self.sFrame.grid(in_=self.cvFrame,row=1)
        for x in range(5):           
            self.sBtn=Button(self.sFrame,text=self.s[x],bg=self.sc[x],fg=self.sf[x],width=20,relief=GROOVE)
            self.sBtn.grid(in_=self.sFrame,row=x)
            self.sBtn.bind('<Button-1>',self.destF)

    #detroy frame back to main title
    def destF(self,event):
        self.sFrame.destroy()

#root window
root=Tk()
root.title('Built Up Rates')
root.geometry('220x600+0+0')
A=mainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

got it :) by using 'if' statements... works well in ranged object and assign the parameters is there any other way to make it much more simpler like inheritance or global definition perhaps?